# Submitting double values to Google Play service's LeaderBoard

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

well , normally I want to submit value as a double to my leaderboard in google play service
but it says submit method is for "long value"

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore
```

> void com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.Leaderboards.submitScore(GoogleApiClient arg0, String arg1, **long arg2**)

So how how can I submit double or float values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both a `double` and a `float`, you can just cast it over to a `long` like this:

```
long arg2 = (long) yourDoubleOrFloat;
```

However, keep in mind that both a `double` and a `float` are unprecise, as they are floating point numbers. You may want to be using `int`'s.

Comment: Actually I find a way, which is, There are some properties in "android developer console Game services" score formatting. addable till 4 Number of decimal place. it means for examlpe, my long value  123456 but people see at leaderboard 12.3456

Answer (score 10):

See [this documentation page](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.html#submitScore%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20long%29):

```
void submitScore (GoogleApiClient apiClient, String leaderboardId, long score)
```

`score` has to be a of type `long`, but:

> The meaning of the score value **depends on the formatting of the
>   leaderboard established in the developer console**. Leaderboards support
>   the following score formats:
>
> - **Fixed-point:** score represents a raw value, and **will be formatted based
>     on the number of decimal places configured**. A score of 1000 would be
>     formatted as 1000, 100.0, or 10.00 for 0, 1, or 2 decimal places.
> - **Time:** score represents an elapsed time in milliseconds. The value will
>     be formatted as an appropriate time value.
> - **Currency:** score represents
>     a value in micro units. For example, in USD, a score of 100 would
>     display as $0.0001, while a score of 1000000 would display as $1.00

So you probably want to head over to the `developer console` and set your desired configuration.